# Microsoft Outlook O365 "Add-In Error" With Automatic Restart

Tags: office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins, appsource

Recently I have been seeing my Microsoft O365 add-in load with this error:

> [Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fNax.png) ADD-IN ERROR Sorry, we had to restart because this add-in wasn't responding.

The console/dev tools shows no error logged at all and then the add-in procedes to restart and run just fine. Is there any reason why add-ins fail to load on occasion without *specific* errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, web add-ins are restarted if any action takes more than 330 ms (5s). You can use a WebWorker to launch long-running tasks. For example, see [Long operations crash Office addin (JS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42438093/long-operations-crash-office-addin-js).

Comment: Hi @Eugene , I am facing similar issue with our office word web addin. After getting first slice of data , it gives the error "Sorry, We had to restart because this add-in was not responding". We are using the same code as mentioned in [link] (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/word/get-the-whole-document-from-an-add-in-for-word) . No matter the size of slice, it gives error after getting 1st slice of data. Please suggest!

Comment: I'd suggest posting a separate question in a new thread so readers could easily recognize questions and answers.