# Unable to debug Excel Add-in in Office 365 Environment with Visual studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio-2019, excel-addins

I am working on an Asp.net core project in which I created an Excel Addin for Office 365. The problem is that I could not debug the javascript code, because the Addin was automatically restarted after a few seconds and I got an error message: "sorry we had to restart because this addin was not responding". Could somebody help me resolve this issue? Many thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Long operations crash Office addin (JS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42438093/long-operations-crash-office-addin-js)

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not answer my question. This tackles the issue with operations that take a long time to execute. But my problem is about debugging. There is no limit (almost) in how long you want to stop at a breakpoint. I do not have this issue with Office 2016, but for Office 365, it is always restarted when I am just in the middle of the debugging process.